# In pdf document created with bookdown codelines are too long

Tags: line-breaks, bookdown, pdflatex

I am trying to write my thesis with bookdown, via RStudio, since I am not so familiar with Latex.
I want to add the code I generated for the project in the appendix but the lines don't break so the code always runs over the page.

I tried so much over a long period that I don't know anymore what I tried or what maybe interferes. I tried to change the size of in the code chunk, but it didn't do anything (so here: `{r app, eval = FALSE, size = "tiny"}` )

Another idea was to change the rotation of the paper but I couldn't manage that either, maybe I wrote it on the wrong page?

I would appreciate it so much if anyone can help me. Thank you!

My index file looks like this:

````
---
title: "Thesis"
site: "bookdown::bookdown_site"
documentclass: book
output:
bookdown::pdf_book:
keep_tex: true
extra_dependencies: ["float"]
citation_package: biblatex
toc: true
toc_depth: 3
includes:
in_header:
- \usepackage{pdfpages}
bibliography: [file.bib]
link-citations: yes
geometry: "left=4cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
---

And the head of the appendix document with an example of code that ist way too long:
# Appendix: Codes {.unnumbered #appendix}
\markboth{APPENDIX}{}

## app.R {-}
```{r app, eval = FALSE} 
  # Inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------

  ## Transform excel input data
  input_data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    
    # functions used here are generated in 02_functions.r
    headers  <- read_excel(input$file$datapath, col_names = FALSE, n_max = 2) %>% tibble::as_tibble() %>% mutate(...3 = NA)
    data     <- read_excel(input$file$datapath, col_names = FALSE, skip = 2)  %>% tibble::as_tibble()
    return(data)
  })

```
````

This leads to something like this:

[image]

I tried:

- to change the code size in the code chunk options
- to change the rotation of the page
- to use  \usepackage{fvextra}
- to use \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\{}}
- to use \lstset{breaklines=true} in the in_header section of the index.Rmd
- to use an extra tex file with
  %\usepackage{fvextra}
  %\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\{}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
---
title: "Thesis"
site: "bookdown::bookdown_site"
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: true
extra_dependencies: ["float"]
citation_package: biblatex
toc: true
toc_depth: 3
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdfpages}
- \usepackage{fvextra}
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\},breaklines=true, breakanywhere=true}
link-citations: yes
geometry: "left=4cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
---

And the head of the appendix document with an example of code that ist way too long:
# Appendix: Codes {.unnumbered #appendix}
\markboth{APPENDIX}{}

## app.R {-}
```{r app, eval = FALSE} 
  # Inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------

  ## Transform excel input data
  input_data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    
    # functions used here are generated in 02_functions.r
    headers  <- read_excel(input$file$datapath, col_names = FALSE, n_max = 2) %>% tibble::as_tibble() %>% mutate(...3 = NA)
    data     <- read_excel(input$file$datapath, col_names = FALSE, skip = 2)  %>% tibble::as_tibble()
    return(data)
  })

```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I am sure I tried something like that before but I did now again and needed to update tinytex. 
Still I get some errors: 
tlmgr.pl: command log updated: C:/Users/natal/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
! Dimension too large.
\fb@put@frame ...p \ifdim \dimen@ >\ht \@tempboxa 
                                                  \fb@putboxa #1\fb@afterfra...
l.1481 \end{Shaded}

Fehler: LaTeX failed to compile _main.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See _main.log for more info.

Comment: I think this is the error causing it:

! Dimension too large.
\fb@put@frame ...p \ifdim \dimen@ >\ht \@tempboxa 
                                                  \fb@putboxa #1\fb@afterfra...
l.1482 \end{Shaded}

Comment: So I think I managed it finally. Thank you so much @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
I needed to add:

header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdfpages}
- \usepackage{fvextra}
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\},breaklines=true, breakanywhere=true,breakautoindent=false}